# Sticky Item Decoration that draws over items RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration, stickyrecycleview

I'm implementing a sticky header item decoration, but I'm trying to make the header overlay the item. I'm basing the code on timehop's library.

https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview

With how it's designed, the item decoration will still create a row, but I want it have a height of 0 within the actual list.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.
[image]

And here is the code for the current sticky item decoration that takes creates its own row. There are a few areas that I've played around with by changing the `Rect` it uses, but I cannot get the right result.

```
override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
    val itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
    if (itemPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
        return
    }
    if (mHeaderPositionCalculator.hasNewHeader(itemPosition, mOrientationProvider.isReverseLayout(parent))) {
        val header = getHeaderView(parent, itemPosition)
        setItemOffsetsForHeader(outRect, header, mOrientationProvider.getOrientation(parent))
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the offsets for the first item in a section to make room for the header view
 *
 * @param itemOffsets rectangle to define offsets for the item
 * @param header      view used to calculate offset for the item
 * @param orientation used to calculate offset for the item
 */
private fun setItemOffsetsForHeader(itemOffsets: Rect, header: View, orientation: Int) {
    mDimensionCalculator.initMargins(mTempRect, header)

    // should I modify itemOffsets here?
    if (orientation == LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
        itemOffsets.top =header.height + mTempRect.top + mTempRect.bottom
    } else {
        itemOffsets.left = header.width + mTempRect.left + mTempRect.right
    }
}

override fun onDrawOver(canvas: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    super.onDrawOver(canvas, parent, state)

    val childCount = parent.childCount
    if (childCount <= 0 || mAdapter.itemCount <= 0) {
        return
    }

    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        val itemView = parent.getChildAt(i)
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(itemView)
        if (position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            continue
        }

        val hasStickyHeader = mHeaderPositionCalculator.hasStickyHeader(itemView, mOrientationProvider.getOrientation(parent), position)
        if (hasStickyHeader || mHeaderPositionCalculator.hasNewHeader(position, mOrientationProvider.isReverseLayout(parent))) {
            val header = mHeaderProvider.getHeader(parent, position)
            //re-use existing Rect, if any.
            var headerOffset: Rect? = mHeaderRects.get(position)
            if (headerOffset == null) {
                headerOffset = Rect()
                mHeaderRects.put(position, headerOffset)
            }


            mHeaderPositionCalculator.initHeaderBounds(headerOffset, parent, header, itemView, hasStickyHeader)
            // should I modify headerOffset here?
            mRenderer.drawHeader(parent, canvas, header, headerOffset)
        }
    }
}
```